# Nginx and wildacard in domain name

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, wildcard-subdomain

Let's say I have a wildcard domain name - *.example.com

I make request to test.example.com and it works.

How do I store the **test** part in header? Is there a nginx variable that can be used?

Tried uncle google, but have not found an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by storing the test part in the header? Please explain your full use case.

Comment: I would like to have the 'test' part set as header and returned in response.

Comment: The full domain name is available as `$http_host` or `$host`. If you are looking for part of the domain name, you will need to use a regular expression. Either [using server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) or [using a map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).